# Lampreys and the origin of certain brain structures

Tags: brain, genomics, phylogenetics

I'm not sure why, but I'd been under the impression that things like the optic tectum and basal ganglia developed post-2R (the double duplication of the genome ~1/2 Ga).

Lampreys (as far as I'm aware), also have these brain structures. The problem is that [TimeTree](http://timetreebeta.igem.temple.edu/) seems to indicate that - unless the outlier of Otsuka et al is correct - lampreys diverged before then:

[image: estimations of human-lamprey divergence times]

While trying to figure out which bit of my thinking is wrong, I came across [this article](http://phys.org/news/2014-02-lamprey-genome-reveals-insights-history.html) that suggests lampreys had whole genome duplications, but completely separately to those in our lineage.

Does this mean that their structures evolved convergently? (Perhaps they're "obvious" things to evolve post-WGDs?) Or is my initial assumption wrong, and the structures are much older than 2R and pre-divergence from lampreys?

Or something else entirely? I'm confused, and I'm sure I'm missing something: I just don't know what.